# Upgrading Unity from 5.1 to 5.3.4 has broken game, specifically models made in Blender

Tags: unity, shaders, models, blender, bug

I recently decided to upgrade Unity after putting it off for some time as I have a rather sizable project started in 5.1.  I knew there would be some hurdles, however, I have had very little luck in getting the game back up and running in the new version.  My Blender model animations seem to be gone and many of the faces are disappearing.  For example a characters arm is just missing and other similar issues across models.  The warning I'm getting seems to be due, at least in part, to a shader I'm using attached to a prefab, however, when I change it to even the standard shader Im still getting the warnings and the issues persist.

[image]

My question is:  Is there something I'm missing in the upgrade process that can make the transition easier, because right now, it would seem I need to recreate all of my Blender assets and reassign all of my materials and not be able to use some of my shaders?

The process in which I upgraded was very simple.  I just opened the project folder with the new version of Unity and rebuilt the project for the new version.

Any help from anyone who has experience migrating projects between different versions of Unity would be appreciated.

Comment: Try closing Unity, deleting your `Library` folder, then re-launching the editor. It will regenerate all the data from your source files. This can sometimes resolve data corruption errors.

Comment: @DMGregory Tried this, unfortunately it did not fix the errors.  I can't even find a way to see which shaders are causing the errors.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to eliminate all of the GpuProgram warnings and also fix all of my animations by trial and error elimination of several shaders and additionally re-importing the models from Blender.  Steps as follows.

1. I set all of the models to use the standard shader in Unity.
2. I then deleted and reloaded the offending shaders and did not have any errors, this fixed the GpuProgram warnings.
3. To fix the animations and models missing faces etc. I went into
   Blender and saved the models in the project asset directory over
   their originals.
4. Unity seemed happy with the new imports and all models/shaders are
   now working.

I'm not sure why just deleting the library folder didn't work in this case, it seems like it would achieve the same thing.  This was a lot of work but ultimately got me back to where I was before upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your fix. It's just a guess but the animation issue could have had something to do with the .meta files and the automatic project upgrade process messing them up somehow. Comparing the old to the new re-exported ones could tell.